# Expanding a compact subset of $\mathbb R^n$

Tags: general-topology, compactness

Note: A set $X \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is covering compact if every open cover of $X$ has a finite subcover.

If $U \in \mathbb{R}^n$ is open and $C \subset U$ is covering compact, show that there is a covering compact set $D$ such that $C \subset \text{int}(D)$ and $D \subset U$.

Here's my thinking so far. Let $$ be the set consisting of open balls of radius one around each point $ \in $. Then we have
$$ \subset \bigcup_{\beta \in S}{\beta}.$$
Since $⊂$ and $$ is covering compact, there exists a subcover $′⊂$ such that
$$⊂ \bigcup_{\beta \in S′}{}.$$
I'm trying to see if this subcover ′ can be turned into a closed, bounded set, but I'm having trouble. Any help?

Comment: What have you tried?  Also, I'm not sure the phrase "covering compact" is standard though I think I know what it means.  It might be helpful for you to define it.

Comment: I don't know whether that statement is true in general topological spaces, but it looks like you're working in $\Bbb R^n$.  Is that correct?

Rather than putting your attempts in comments, it's better form to put them directly into your question.  That way people scanning the question list can see that you've made an effort *before* making the decision whether to click through.

Comment: Yes, i'm working in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: Please edit your question to be self-contained by adding that fact and by adding your attempts to solve the proble, as set forth in your comments.

Comment: okay, i moved it

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**  This isn't true in general topological spaces so you'll need to use the properties of $\Bbb R_n$.  If $C$ is compact, then it also must be closed.  Use that fact to put an open ball around every point of $C$ that is bounded away from the complement of $U$.  Now use compactness to pick finitely many such balls and take their closure.  That's the set you'll want.

I've left a lot of details for you to work out.

Comment: Do you mean put an open ball around every point of $C$ that is bounded away from the complement of $C$?

Comment: No, that won't be possible for points on the boundary of $C$.

Answer (score 1):

For each $p\in C$ take $r_p>0$ such that the open ball $B(p,r_p)$ is a subset of $U.$ Then $\{B(p,r_p/2):p\in C\}$ is an open cover of $C,$ so take a finite $C^*\subset C$ such that $C\subset \cup \{B(p,r_p/2):p\in C^*\}.$ Let $D$ be the closure of $\cup \{B(p,r_p/2):p\in C^*\}.$

Answer (score 0):

$U$ is open so $U'$ is closed. Also, $C\cap U'=\emptyset$ since $C\subset U.$ Since $C$ is compact and  [the distance between disjoint compact set and closed set in a metric space is positive](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Distance_between_Disjoint_Compact_Set_and_Closed_Set_in_Metric_Space_is_Positive), $d(C,U')=\epsilon>0.$ Let
$$D=\overline{\bigcup_{x\in C} B(x,\epsilon/2)}.$$
Then $D$ is closed, $C\subset D.$ Finally, $D\subset U$ because otherwise $D\cap U'$ would be non-empty and there would be an element $y\in D\cap U'$ so that $d(C,U')\leq d(C,y)\leq\epsilon/2.$

Answer (score 0):

Let $X$ be any [regular](https://topology.pi-base.org/properties/P000011), [locally compact](https://topology.pi-base.org/properties/P000023) topological space (such as $\mathbb R^n$). Then $X$ has this property: for each compact $C$ and open $U\supseteq C$, there is a compact $D$ with $C\subseteq int(D)\subseteq D\subseteq U$.

To see this, for each $c\in C$ choose a neighborhood $V_c$ of $c$ whose closure is compact (by locally compact) and a subset of $U$ (by regular), that is, where $c\in V_c\subseteq cl(V_c)\subseteq U$.

Then $\{V_c:c\in C\}$ covers $C$, so choose $\{c_n:n<N\}\subseteq C$ with $C\subseteq V=\bigcup\{V_{c_n}:n<N\}$. Then $D=\bigcup\{cl(V_{c_n}):n<N\}\subseteq U$ is compact with $C\subseteq V\subseteq int(D)\subseteq D\subseteq U$.